# JavaScript swapping inputted values of radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, radio-button

I'm a beginner making my first JavaScript app.  Its a diet app designed to calculate the user's BMR (calories burned in 24 hrs).  For it to work, the user needs to enter their height and weight.  I want to give the user the opportunity to enter these details in Imperial units *or* Metric units.

I've designed a simple HTML form.  The form has two radio buttons, one for Imperial and one for Metric.  The HTML is:

```
<input type="radio" checked="checked" id="imperial" name="measurement" value="imperial"><label for="imperial">Imperial</label>

<input type="radio" id="metric" name="measurement" value="metric"><label for="metric">Metric</label>
```

Because I live in the UK, and because most people here still use Imperial units for their height and weight, I added `checked="checked"` to the first input tag to pre-select the Imperial radio button.

In the JavaScript I used the following line to assign both radio buttons to the same variable:

```
const units = document.getElementsByName("measurement");
```

I console logged `units` and, as expected, the value was a node list with two items.  This is the console output:

```
NodeList(2) [input#imperial, input#metric]
0: input#imperial
1: input#metric
length: 2
```

As you can see, Imperial is first in the list, at position zero.  I wanted to use this to assign the user's choice to a different variable, which I could then use later on.  For this, I created the following `if` statement:

```
for(i = 0; i < units.length; i++) {
    if(units[i].checked) {
      unitUsed = "imperial";
    } else {
      unitUsed = "metric";
    }
  }
```

Let's say the user has opted not to click the Metric radio button.  Imperial will still be checked.  The first time the loop runs, it asks *"Is the item at position zero in the node list checked?*  The answer should be 'yes'.  Therefore, the variable `unitUsed` should be given "Imperial" as a value.

However, when I `console.log(unitUsed)` it tells me the value is Metric.  And when I submit the form again and choose Metric, JS tells me the value of unitUsed is Imperial.  It's doing the exact diametric opposite of what I want.

I've been staring at this for half an hour and I can't see the flaw in the logic.  Can anyone help me out?  Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is happening because you are reassigning the value on the second iteration. To explain it better -

```
for(i = 0; i < units.length; i++) {
  console.log({ checked: units[i].checked })
  if(units[i].checked) {
    unitUsed = "imperial";
  } else {
    unitUsed = "metric";
  }
}
```

I added a console after for loop so on the first iteration **units[0].checked** is true so **unitUsed** is assigned with value imperial. on the second iteration **units[1].checked** is false so it going to else block and assigning **metric** to **unitUsed** variable.

To make it work you can add a break statement simply after assigning new value. Like this -

```
for(i = 0; i < units.length; i++) {
  if(units[i].checked) {
    unitUsed = "imperial";
    break;
  } else {
    unitUsed = "metric";
    break;
  }
}
```

**Or better you can add a click event listener on radio button so whenever they get clicked you assign value to unitUsed this way you will have the latest selected unit.**

```
<body>
    <div class="radio-buttons-choice" id="container-3-radio-buttons-choice">

  <input type="radio" checked="checked" id="imperial" name="measurement" onclick="checkRadio(name)" value="imperial"><label for="imperial">Imperial</label>

<input type="radio" id="metric" name="measurement" onclick="checkRadio(name)" value="metric"><label for="metric">Metric</label>

    </div>

<script>
let unitUsed = "imperial"; //default checked value
function checkRadio(name) {
    unitUsed = name;
    alert(unitUsed)
}
</script>
</body>
```